# Counting same Elements in a dataframe r

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

got another problem with r dataframes.

```
#starting position
from <- c("A","B","A","C")
to <- c("D","F","D","F")
number <- c(3,4,6,7)
data.frame(from,to,number)
```

How can I count the numbers of the two same "from-to" relations (from A to D)?
The result should look like my "result" dataframe.

```
#result
from <- c("A","B","C")
to <- c("D","F","F")
result <- c(9,4,7)
data.frame(from,to,result)
```

Thank you guys :)

Comment: Many ways `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(from, to) %>% summarise(result = sum(number))` or `aggregate(number ~ ., df, sum)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_by` to group "from" and "to" then use sum in summarise to get the total for each of the groups.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(from,to) %>% summarise(result = sum(number))
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of @akrun's comment. Did you see it?

Comment: I did not. glad someone else had the same idea.